# Python inheritance - Interfaces/classes

Tags: python, inheritance, langchain

```
from langchain.schema import BaseMemory

class ChatMemory(BaseMemory):
   def __init__(self, user_id: UUID, type: str):
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.type = type

   # implemented abstract methods

class AnotherMem(ChatMemory):
    def __init__(self, user_id: UUID, type: str):
        super().__init__(user_id, type)
```

This seems simple enough - but I get an error: `ValueError: "AnotherMem" object has no field "user_id"`. What am I doing wrong?

Note that [BaseMemory](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/db45970a66f39a32f2cdd83e7bde26a404efad7b/langchain/schema.py#L188) is an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `BaseMemory` from [langchain](https://pypi.org/project/langchain/) is defined as a [pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/) model, which has strict rules for defining instance attributes. Instead of using a constructor method, use the standard pydantic syntax of declaring expected instance attributes on the child class.

```
import uuid
from langchain.schema import BaseMemory


class ChatMemory(BaseMemory):
    user_id: uuid.UUID
    type: str

    ...

class AnotherMem(ChatMemory):
    pass


print(AnotherMem(user_id=uuid.uuid4(), type="foo").user_id)
```

```
d952d62e-79e0-4cf4-a786-d23d880f96a2
```

Comment: @user2816215 Glad to help. As a side note, consider renaming the attribute `type` to something else. It's not quite as bad to shadow the [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs) on attributes as it is for regular variable names.. but it does end up tripping up both linters and people alike (*as can even be seen by the stack overflow syntax highlighting on this answer*) :)

Comment: agreed. That's a valid point. Thanks.